# The efficient way to convert struct to bson and bson to struct

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, bson

What is the correct way to convert a struct to bson or bson to struct from the point of view of server performance?

```golang
bsonAsByte, err = bson.Marshal(&bsonData)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonAsByte, &user)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most responses always use **bson.Marshal()** followed by **bson.Unmarshal()**, but this form is slower.

Imagine that you are on a server with thousands of accesses to the database per second. Your code can slow down server operation depending on the quality of the code.
For this reason, I always do the benchmark tests before choosing which method to use.

An example is shown below:

```golang
package bsontest

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type User struct {
    UniqueID    string    `bson:"_id"`
    Name        string    `bson:"name"`
    Password    string    `bson:"password"`
    Email       string    `bson:"email"`
    Age         int       `bson:"age"`
    Admin       bool      `bson:"admin"`
}

func (e *User) FromBson(data bson.M) (err error) {
    var tagValue string

    element := reflect.ValueOf(e).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < element.NumField(); i += 1 {
        typeField := element.Type().Field(i)
        tag := typeField.Tag

        tagValue = tag.Get("bson")

        if tagValue == "-" {
            continue
        }

        switch element.Field(i).Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            switch data[tagValue].(type) {
            case string:
                element.Field(i).SetString(data[tagValue].(string))

            default:
                err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a string")
                return
            }

        case reflect.Bool:
            switch data[tagValue].(type) {
            case bool:
                element.Field(i).SetBool(data[tagValue].(bool))

            default:
                err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a boolean")
                return
            }

        case reflect.Int:
            switch data[tagValue].(type) {
            case int:
                element.Field(i).SetInt(int64(data[tagValue].(int)))
            case int64:
                element.Field(i).SetInt(data[tagValue].(int64))
            default:
                err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a integer")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    return
}

func (e *User) ToBson() (data bson.M) {
    var tagValue string

    data = bson.M{}
    element := reflect.ValueOf(e).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < element.NumField(); i += 1 {
        typeField := element.Type().Field(i)
        tag := typeField.Tag

        tagValue = tag.Get("bson")

        if tagValue == "-" {
            continue
        }

        switch element.Field(i).Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            value := element.Field(i).String()
            data[tagValue] = value

        case reflect.Bool:
            value := element.Field(i).Bool()
            data[tagValue] = value

        case reflect.Int:
            value := element.Field(i).Int()
            data[tagValue] = value
        }
    }

    return
}

var user User

func init() {
    user = User{
        UniqueID: "12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
        Name:     "Fulano da Silva Sauro",
        Password: "pangea",
        Email:    "sauro@pangea.com",
        Admin:    true,
    }
}

func ExampleUser_ToBson() {
    var err error
    var userAsBSon = user.ToBson()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", userAsBSon)

    user = User{}
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user)

    err = user.FromBson(userAsBSon)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user)

    // Output:
    // map[_id:12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL admin:true age:0 email:sauro@pangea.com name:Fulano da Silva Sauro password:pangea]
    // {UniqueID: Name: Password: Email: Age:0 Admin:false}
    // {UniqueID:12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL Name:Fulano da Silva Sauro Password:pangea Email:sauro@pangea.com Age:0 Admin:true}
}

func Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal(b *testing.B) {
    var err error
    var bsonAsByte []byte
    var bsonData bson.M

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bsonAsByte, err = bson.Marshal(&user)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonAsByte, &bsonData)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal(b *testing.B) {
    var err error
    var bsonAsByte []byte
    var bsonData = bson.M{
        "_id":"12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
        "admin":true,
        "age":0,
        "email":"sauro@pangea.com",
        "name":"Fulano da Silva Sauro",
        "password":"pangea",
    }

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bsonAsByte, err = bson.Marshal(&bsonData)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonAsByte, &user)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func Benchmark_UsingFromBson(b *testing.B) {
    var err error
    var bsonData = bson.M{
        "_id":"12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
        "admin":true,
        "age":0,
        "email":"sauro@pangea.com",
        "name":"Fulano da Silva Sauro",
        "password":"pangea",
    }

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        err = user.FromBson(bsonData)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func Benchmark_UsingToBson(b *testing.B) {
    var bsonData bson.M

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bsonData = user.ToBson()
    }

    _ = bsonData
}
```

Timers:

```
Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal
Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal-8      398800          2996 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingToBson
Benchmark_UsingToBson-8                   1789176         643.0 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingFromBson
Benchmark_UsingFromBson-8                 2128242         539.6 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal
Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal-8      474501          2524 ns/op
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what is the point of using reflection on a known type? If you're gonna write ToBson/FromBson manually for every individual type you want to write/read from the db, specifically because of performance concerns, shouldn't you then try to drop the reflection? In addition to dropping reflection I'd recommend you write a generator for these methods, maintaining all of them manually on a large set of types is gonna hurt.